# How to create a table with a list of OU in AD using powershell

Tags: bash, powershell, active-directory

I have in my active directory a number of subfolders and I want to count the number of users there. I found a way to do with powershell and the Get ADUser command, however I think there must be a way to optimize this to build a table with all the subfolders I want.

[image]

normally the following script works for me, but I don't know if I can recursively go through all the subfolders and finally create a csv with the number of users per subfolder.

```
echo "ACC - total:" (Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase 'OU=Users,OU=ACC,OU=Clients,DC=SSICloud,DC=local' ).count

 echo "All Car - total:" (Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase 'OU=Users,OU=All Car,OU=Clients,DC=SSICloud,DC=local' ).count
```

outcome:

```
ACC - Total:
10

All Car - Total: 
11
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Get-ADOrganizationalUnit`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/get-adorganizationalunit?view=windowsserver2022-ps) can search recursively through all OUs in your Domain, you can then pass the `DistinguishedName` of the OU as argument to the `-SearchBase` parameter of [`Get-ADUser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/get-aduser?view=windowsserver2022-ps) to get your report:

```sh
Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter * -Properties CanonicalName | ForEach-Object {
    [pscustomobject]@{
        OUCanonicalName = $_.CanonicalName
        TotalUserCount  = @(Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase $_.DistinguishedName).Count
    }
} | Export-Csv .... -NoTypeInformation
```